# How to call scope dynamically

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-scope

I have in the View several models called dia1 dia2, etc.
I'm trying to invoke them from the controller dynamically in the following way

```
for(i=1; i<=7; i++){
  Console.log($scope.day[i]);
}
```

It always shows as NULL or NaN

Thank you in advance for your precious help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.day` is not an array, since you described having variables such as `day1`, `day2`...

You can access them like so:
`$scope['day' + i]`